# Spring security validation of AWS Cognito JWT token for specific role not working - 403 response

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to validate if the JWT token from my Cognito user pool has the correct role in my Spring security config. (getting 403 response)

my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .addFilterBefore(customRoleFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) //TODO:: does not work!
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/products").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/products/**").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(new JWTDecoder()))) //TODO:: also tried to map roles but doesn't work either.
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomRoleFilter customRoleFilter() {
        return new CustomRoleFilter();
    }
}
```

tried to add roles in the filter but did not work:

```
public class CustomRoleFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // TODO:: Extract roles from JWT token (cognito user:groups claim).
        List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("USER", "ADMIN");

        // Create authorities from roles.
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Create an Authentication object with the authorities.
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                new User("username", "password", authorities),
                null,
                authorities
        );

        // Set the Authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder.
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        // Continue with the filter chain.
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

also tried to add the roles ion the JWT decoder, this didn't work either. (don't think is the right place to do this?)

```
public class JWTDecoder implements JwtDecoder {
    @Override
    public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
        try {
            // https://cognito-idp.region.amazonaws.com/user-pool-id/.well-known/jwks.json.
            //TODO:: verify the JWT token
            
            var parsedJwt = JWTParser.parse(token);
            Map<String, Object> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>(parsedJwt.getHeader().toJSONObject());
            Map<String, Object> claims = new LinkedHashMap<>(parsedJwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getClaims());
            if (claims.get(JwtClaimNames.IAT) instanceof Date) {
                var iat = ((Date) claims.get(JwtClaimNames.IAT)).toInstant();
                claims.put(JwtClaimNames.IAT, iat);
            }
            if (claims.get(JwtClaimNames.EXP) instanceof Date) {
                var exp = ((Date) claims.get(JwtClaimNames.EXP)).toInstant();
                claims.put(JwtClaimNames.EXP, exp);
            }

            //TODO:: does not work either
            claims.put("roles", List.of("USER", "ADMIN").toArray());

            return Jwt.withTokenValue(parsedJwt.getParsedString())
                    .headers(h -> h.putAll(headers))
                    .claims(c -> c.putAll(claims))
                    .build();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JwtException("Provided token is not valid");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new JwtException("Error during parse token");
        }
    }
}
```

example of user group(which should be mapped to role) in JWT payload:

"cognito:groups": [
"USER"
],

I tried to add a before filter to my security config to extract the roles from the Cognito JWT token. (cognito:groups claim)

I also tried to extract the roles from the Cognito JWT token in the JWTDecoder, but I don't think this is the right place to do this?

I also tried to add an authentication manager where I tried to extract the roles from the Cognito JWT token, this didn't work either.

Can anyone help me, or send me in the right direction?

Comment: No we cant send you in the correct direction because of a couple of reasons, first you have not shown us what your JWT token looks like, and described properly what it is you want to do. You have also not posted any DEBUG logs so that we can see the clear reason for your 403. Third of all you have clearly not read the spring security documentation JWT chapter that clearly explains how to extract/convert the scope claim to proper granted authorities

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by removing custom Decoder and adding a custom jwtAuthenticationConverter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/products").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/products/**").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> {
                                    jwt.jwkSetUri("https://cognito-idp.region.amazonaws.com/user-pool-id/.well-known/jwks.json"); // Decode and verify the JWT token
                                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthenticationConverter()); // Necessary to convert AWS Cognito claim "cognito:groups" into ROLES
                                }
                        )
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter customJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        return new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter();
    }
}



public class CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    private static final String COGNITO_GROUPS = "cognito:groups";


    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt source) {
        List<String> roles = (List<String>) source.getClaims().get(COGNITO_GROUPS);

        // Create authorities from roles.
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(source, authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted: providing with an authentication converter is actually the way the [official doc recommends to go](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction). As an easier alternative, you could consider using [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#oidc-starter) which allows to define authorities mapping from just properties (no java conf at all required if you use `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('USER')` and just a bean if you prefer access control in conf)